Writing a function: Why does dplyr select() work with quoted column name but df$col_name does not?
I've been reading posts and documentation about 'tidy evaluation,' but my results don't make sense with what I'm reading. My function is:
ttsplit = function(prepped_data, outcome_column){
  
  sample <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), nrow(prepped_data), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.7,0.3))
  train  <- prepped_data[sample, ]
  test   <- prepped_data[!sample, ]
  
  Xtrain = train %>% 
    select(!outcome_column)
  
  ytrain = train$outcome_column
  
  Xtest = test %>% 
    select(!outcome_column)
  
  ytest = test$outcome_column
  
  return(list(Xtrain, ytrain, Xtest, ytest))
}

My questions are:

My understanding is that inside a select() statement, I need to unquote my column name using {{outcome_column}}. However, it works fine as is. Why?

ytrain = train$outcome_column doesn't work. The first and third items in the list datasets are correct and the second and fourth are NULL.


datasets = ttsplit(model1data, "SalePrice")

Warning messages:
1: Unknown or uninitialised column: `outcome_column`. 
2: Unknown or uninitialised column: `outcome_column`. 

> datasets[2]
[[1]]
NULL

> datasets[4]
[[1]]
NULL

The line train${{outcome_column}} is invalid so how do you unquote in this situation? (My current solution is to use a select() statement, which is fine, but I want to understand.)

Furthermore, if I simply run df$'column_name' outside of a function, it works. Why?

> model1data$'SalePrice'
   [1] 208500 181500 223500...

My data is like this, but with more columns.
> model1data
# A tibble: 1,460 × 3
      Id LotArea SalePrice
   <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
 1     1    8450    208500
 2     2    9600    181500
 3     3   11250    223500
 4     4    9550    140000
 5     5   14260    250000
 6     6   14115    143000
 7     7   10084    307000
 8     8   10382    200000
 9     9    6120    129900
10    10    7420    118000
# … with 1,450 more rows

Here's the dput version:
structure(list(Id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), LotArea = c(8450, 
9600, 11250, 9550, 14260, 14115, 10084, 10382, 6120, 7420), SalePrice = c(208500, 
181500, 223500, 140000, 250000, 143000, 307000, 2e+05, 129900, 
118000)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))





In your code there is an ambiguity between a column that would be called "outcome_column" and one called "SalesPrice", the best thing to do here is not to use {{ }} but to use one_of().

and 3.

train$outcome_column is equivalent to train$"outcome_column". That's how the dollar operator works, outcome_column is not evaluated, you can do train[[outcome_column]] however
